# how do i change state on this navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i'm trying to figure out why the prop i want to pass won't work with the toggle function:

```
function custToggle({e}){
    e.custOrFalse= !e.custOrFalse;
    var custButton='cust page'
    if ( e.custOrFalse==true ) {
      custButton='cust login' 
    };
    return custButton
  }
  
  const Navbar = ({...props},{children}) => {
  
    //can set this navbar to be cust based or not
    var custButton='cust page'
    if ( props.custOrFalse==true ) {
      custButton='cust login' 
    };
  
          const [grid, makeGrid] = useState(false); //whatever is inside the parenthesis is the starting value
          const [publish, makePublish] = useState(false);
          const [research, makeResearch] = useState(false);
  
          return (
            <div>
                <nav className = {`${styles.page__menu} ${styles.page__custom_settings} ${styles.menu}`} >
                  <ul className = {`${styles.menu__list} ${styles.r_list}`} >
                      <CustomNavButtonLeft navButton='the grid'       onClick=''  />
                      <CustomNavButtonLeft navButton='publish'        onClick=''  />
                      <CustomNavButtonLeft navButton='research'       onClick=''  />
                      <CustomNavButtonRight navButton={custButton}  onClick={(e)=>{custToggle(e)}}  />
                  </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
          );
      };
  
  
  export default Navbar;
```

i also tried `onClick={custToggle(custOrFalse)}`

and `onclick={custToggle(this.custOrFalse)}`

and `onclick={custToggle(props.custOrFalse)}`

so, clearly i'm missing the concept here.

also tried this:

```
const [custOrFalse, makeCustToggle] = useState(props.custOrFalse);

  function CustomerToggle(){
    makeCustToggle(!props.custOrFalse);
  }

<CustomNavButtonRight navButton={custButton}  onClick={CustomerToggle}  />
```

what i'd like to do is just have the button rerender - and for the text to change from 'cust page' to 'cust login' -- as well as be able to later render a component depending on which state the button is in.

Comment: weirdly enough, if i add ```alert(dealerOrFalse);``` in the ```CustomerToggle()``` function, it will toggle the value...but the button won't rerender, which i thought changing state would do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `useState` is an async function, trying to invert or update the value based on existing value won't work straight away. You should instead accept an argument that is guaranteed to be the previous updated value and make changes to it.

```
const [custOrFalse, makeCustToggle] = useState(props.custOrFalse);

  function CustomerToggle(){
    makeCustToggle(prevVal=>!prevVal);
  }

<CustomNavButtonRight navButton={custButton}  onClick={CustomerToggle}  />
```

Altogether, your component should look something like this:

```
const Navbar = ({...props},{children}) => {
  
    //can set this navbar to be cust based or not
const [custOrFalse, makeCustToggle] = useState(props.custOrFalse);

  function CustomerToggle(){
    makeCustToggle(prevVal=>!prevVal);
  }
    var custButton='cust page'
    if (custOrFalse===true ) {
      custButton='cust login' 
    };
  
          const [grid, makeGrid] = useState(false); //whatever is inside the parenthesis is the starting value
          const [publish, makePublish] = useState(false);
          const [research, makeResearch] = useState(false);
  
          return (
            <div>
                <nav className = {`${styles.page__menu} ${styles.page__custom_settings} ${styles.menu}`} >
                  <ul className = {`${styles.menu__list} ${styles.r_list}`} >
                      <CustomNavButtonLeft navButton='the grid'       onClick=''  />
                      <CustomNavButtonLeft navButton='publish'        onClick=''  />
                      <CustomNavButtonLeft navButton='research'       onClick=''  />
                      <CustomNavButtonRight navButton={custButton}  onClick={CustomerToggle}  />
                  </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
          );
      };
  
  
  export default Navbar;
```

Comment: awesome. and the ```===``` is a great catch too.

Comment: if i wanted to mount/unmount a component based on this - would i do that in the same CustomerToggle function? or would i somehow bring the value back to the parent and render that way?

Comment: Unless you're checking a parse-able string number and an actual number or something like that, you'd always want to use `===` . Regarding, mounting you could use `useEffect` with appropriate dependencies, and for unmounting, you could return a function within the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: If you'd just want to render a component based on any boolean value. You could  use conditional rendering, like ```{custOrFalse&&<SomeComponent/>}```

Comment: If you're rendering the component conditionally, you can place it in the `return` function within valid opening & closing tags. E.g `return(<div>{custOrFalse&&<Registration/>} </div>)`

Comment: this worked perfectly for me, thank you for taking the time.  i also tried ```{!custOrFalse&&<DLogin/>}``` and of course it renders on start.  so i added a counter on useEffect, and tried to do something like ```counterFirst=counter>1```  and```{counterFirst&&<Registration/>}``` - useEffect doesn't seem to take ```counter=counter++``` would you have any recommendations per chance?

Comment: meant to say ```{counterFirst&&!custOrFalse&&<DLogin/>}```

Comment: `useEffect` is invoked after the component is mounted. And it is invoked whenever the value(s) in the dependency array change. Hence, even though the `counterFirst` value is evaluated, it is not reflected in the UI, because the component altogether is not re-rendered. You could instead define a function to set/update the state of `counterFirst` using 
 `useState` hook and call that function in `useEffect`, but make sure to keep the dependency array empty, else you'll fall into an infinite loop.